# When to turn your alien power face up?

Tags: cosmic-encounter

In the rules it states that after each player chooses their Alien Sheet, it is placed "face down" in front of them.

I can't find in the rules when players should then reveal their alien powers. Do players reveal their alien powers after all have chosen one at the beginning of the game, or are alien powers kept hidden until their powers are used?

Comment: Now that's an interesting oversight.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**By default, alien powers are revealed after everyone has one.** The [rulebook](http://www.ihrysko.sk/buxus/docs/cosmic-encounter-rulebook.pdf) does not make this clear up front, but it must be true since the other option you mention is in the Variants section on p14:

> ### Hidden Powers
>
> In this variant, players leave their alien sheets facedown after
> selecting them at the start of the game. While a player’s alien
> sheet remains facedown, its power cannot be used. A player
> may turn his or her alien sheet faceup at any time in order to
> use it. Once turned faceup, the player’s alien sheet remains
> faceup for the rest of the game.

Comment: I recently got very confused by this with friends who had just learned the game because I had _always_ played with the Hidden Powers variant and the group that they had learned with did not. It took us forever to track down a resolution in the rulebook. FWIW I _still_ always play with the Hidden Powers variant because I think it's more fun!